# Call to a member function escape_string() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function escape_string() on a non-object
```

On the code:

```
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$user = $_GET['user'];
//$id = $_GET['uid'];   
echo "u: ".$user." pass: ".$pass;
echo "</br>TEST";
//$check = validate_password_from_uid($id, $pass);
$check = validate_password_from_username($user, $pass);
echo "validation: </br>";
if (is_array($check)){
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($check);
    echo "</pre>";
}else{
    var_dump($check);
}
```

Here is `validate_password_from_username`:

```
function validate_password_from_username($username, $password)
{
    global $db, $mybb;

    $username = $db->escape_string(strtolower($username));
    switch($mybb->settings['username_method'])
    {
        case 0:
            $query = $db->simple_select("users", "uid,username,password,salt,loginkey,coppauser,usergroup", "LOWER(username)='".$username."'", array('limit' => 1));
            break;
        case 1:
            $query = $db->simple_select("users", "uid,username,password,salt,loginkey,coppauser,usergroup", "LOWER(email)='".$username."'", array('limit' => 1));
            break;
        case 2:
            $query = $db->simple_select("users", "uid,username,password,salt,loginkey,coppauser,usergroup", "LOWER(username)='".$username."' OR LOWER(email)='".$username."'", array('limit' => 1));
            break;
        default:
            $query = $db->simple_select("users", "uid,username,password,salt,loginkey,coppauser,usergroup", "LOWER(username)='".$username."'", array('limit' => 1));
            break;
    }

    $user = $db->fetch_array($query);
    if(!$user['uid'])
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return validate_password_from_uid($user['uid'], $password, $user);
    }
}
```

The error is related to the line 67 in which `$db->escape_string` part is. What  should I change?

Comment: You're expecting `global $db` to be an object, but apparently it isn't, at the time of your call. (That's the problem with `global` in PHP, you never know what you get.)

Comment: @AdamSinclair $db->escape_string

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of concatenating SQL.

Comment: What database layer are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells us that the $db variable is not an object, so you can't make a function call to it. You don't show us how $db is defined so you might have named the variable differently.